# How do I identify whether a number is an integer?

Tags: javascript

This a script that deals with javascript and var type identifications. What you see below is a small project that I'm doing. It is supposed to calculate the x1 and x2 values of the quadratic equation. The problem that I'm having is that I'm unable to make the program identify whether or not the results are in INTEGER form or else

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="matrix_style.css">
<title>JS Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function result(){
    //first the values from table one are stored in the bellow variables:
    a=Number(document.table_1.number1.value);
    b=Number(document.table_1.number2.value);
    c=Number(document.table_1.number3.value);
    // then they are proccessed and stored in the ans1_1 and ans_2 variables:
    ans_1=-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c));
    ans_2=-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c));
    ans_3= "no solution"
    // here is my problem, I can't seem to be able to determine if the variables are integers meaning ... -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...
    // this part is suppose to dispaly the results only if the results are integers and else display "no solution"
    if(return ans_1%1===0 && return ans_2%===0 )
    {
        document.calculator.total_1.value=ans_1;
        document.calculator.total_2.value=ans_2;
    }
    else
    {
        document.calculator.total_3.value=ans_3;
    }

    }
</script>

</head>
  <body>


     <!--First the user inserts the a b and c values into the table bellow-->


    <table class="table_1">
     <form name="table_1" >
       <tr>
           <th>Insert your equation:</th>
           <th></th> 
           <th></th> 


        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td><span id="A" contenteditable><input type="text" name="number1"  ><br></span></td>
            <td><span id="B" contenteditable><input type="text" name="number2"  ><br></span></td>
            <td><span id="C" contenteditable><input type="text" name="number3"  ><br></span></td>

        </tr>


    </form>
   </table>

     <!--The results are suppose to display in table bellow: -->

    <table class="table_result">
     <form name="calculator">
        <tr>

           <th>Result:</th>
            <th></th>     
        </tr>   
        <tr>  
            <td><span id="A_ans" contenteditable><input type="text" name="total_1"  ><br></span></td>
            <td><span id="B_ans" contenteditable><input type="text" name="total_2"  ><br></span></td>   
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><span id="C_ans" contenteditable><input type="text" name="total_3" ><br></span></td>   
        </tr>    
            <input type="button" value="result" id="submit" onclick="javascript:result();">
    </form>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `if(return ans_1%1===0 && return ans_2%===0 )` is a syntax error, it should be

```
if(ans_1%1===0 && ans_2%1===0 )
```

The return  was out of place there *and* the check for `ans_2` was missing the modulus operand.

Additionally, you're passing a subtraction to `Math.pow()`, which may be negative (resulting in a `NaN`).

Comment: still no answer. it only displays the error message. that is suppose to show if the numbers are not integers

Comment: @CashVai That's probably because you're passing the square root negative numbers, which results in a `NaN`. Are you sure your test equation can be solved?

Comment: It does work with adequate numbers, e.g. 1,2,3 → no answer, 1,-5,6 → result

Comment: Also, your math to solve equations is missing the divisions by `2a`

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an "Integer", aka whole number, in Javascript, only [`Number`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

The easiest way to check if they are whole numbers is to [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) them and compare to the original value:

```
if(Math.round(ans_1) === ans_1 && Math.round(ans_2) === ans_2)
{
    document.calculator.total_1.value = ans_1;
    document.calculator.total_2.value = ans_2;
}
else
{
    document.calculator.total_3.value = ans_3;
}
```

Comment: Actually, CashVai's method is also a correct way of checking for whole numbers

Comment: thanks for the accept, but outlyer's answer fixed your original syntax errors with a better explanation so I think you should accept his.

Answer (score 0):

> Check for a remainder when dividing by 1:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

> If you don't know that the argument is a number-

```
function isInt(n){
        return Number(n)===n && n%1===0;
}
```

> Refer this links
>
> [is_int()](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_int:444) => Check if the variable type is Integer and if its
>   content is Integer
>
> [is_float()](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_float:442) => Check if the variable type is Float and if its
>   content is Float